# "DLL Load Failed" When Installing svm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to implement neural network capabilities using Python.  I am trying the scikit-learn module.  I installed **NumPy version 1.8.1**, **SciPy version 0.14.0**, and **matplotlib version 1.1.1** under C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages, with **Python Version 2.7**.  Python and all of the modules are 32-bit.  Everything installed without any problems.  I did the following in the Python window:

```
import os
import numpy, scipy, sklearn
from sklearn import svm
```

The first two imports had no problems, but the "from sklearn import svm" import gave me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py, line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  From "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slkearn\svm\classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError:  DLL load failed:  The specified module could not be found."
```

But the files libsvm.pyd and liblinear.pyd are in fact in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm.
Also, C:\Python27\python.exe is the Python version 2.7 found in the registry.  What am I missing?  Why am I getting this error, even after uninstalling and reinstalling the numpy and scipy libraries?

Comment: How did you install those libraries?

Comment: I used the executables:  numpy-1.8.1-win32-superpack-python2.7, scipy-0.14.0-win32-superpack-python2.7, matplotlib-1.1.1.win32-py2.7, and scikit-learn-0.15.2.win32-py2.7, and followed the wizards.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting up a scientific Python stack on Windows can be a finicky thing to do yourself. By far the simplest way is to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda), which has good support and comes with its own package management system that works well on Windows. Failing that, I suggest you try the pre-built binaries from [Christoph Gohlke's collection](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I solved the "DLL load failed" problem by loading Python 2.7.8, Python (x, y) 2.7.10.0 (which in turn loaded NumPy 1.9.2, SciPy 0.15.1, matplotlib 1.4.3, and scikit-learn 0.16.1), and OpenCV 2.4.0.  Previously, when I was getting the error, I was using Python 2.7.8 along with NumPy 1.8.1, SciPy 0.14.0, and matplotlib 1.1.1.  From that, the problem was the versions of NumPy, SciPy, and matplotlib were too old for building the scientific Python stack.